# Automatically sync using Unison

Tags: unison

I am new to `unison`- the file synchronizing software.

I use `unison` to sync files between my local machine and a remote server. However, I have to do the synchronization manually every time.

Is there a way to trigger unison to synchronize automatically whenever a change is detected in the local folders set to be synchronized?

My OS : `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Check out the `repeat = watch` option.

Or if you want more control over what is watched and exactly what events trigger unison to run, check out `inotify-tools` and write a small script that runs in the background.